# Update tables after editted value on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modal to update value on table. User click edit link on table and fill billing rate on modal form. After save, how to update the table?

_Edit.cshtml (PartialView):

```
@model Namespace.ViewModels.TimeKeeperEditViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Time Keeper</h4>
</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "TimeKeeper", FormMethod.Post,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TimeKeeperID)

    <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="billingRate" class="control-label">Billing Rate</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BillingRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
}
```

Index.cshtml (View)

```
@model Namespace.ViewModels.BillingViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Elite Rate</th>
            <th>e-Bill Rate</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.TimeKeepers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EliteRate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BillingRate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    TimeKeeper timeKeeper = db.TimeKeepers.Find(id);
    TimeKeeperEditViewModel timeKeeperEditVM = new TimeKeeperEditViewModel()
    {
        TimeKeeperID = timeKeeper.TimeKeeperID,
        EliteRate = timeKeeper.EliteRate,
        BillingRate = timeKeeper.BillingRate
    };
    return PartialView("_Edit", timeKeeperEditVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TimeKeeperEditViewModel timeKeeperEditVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TimeKeeper timeKeeper = db.TimeKeepers.Find(timeKeeperEditVM.TimeKeeperID);
        timeKeeper.BillingRate = timeKeeperEditVM.BillingRate;
        db.Entry(timeKeeper).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your _Edit.chstml is included on  your index.cshtml which renders the table.

The easiest way would be to:

1) Put your table into the partial view.

2) Render your table using Html.RenderAction.

3) Then create a javascript function that will reload your partial using $.get or $.ajax (if you use jquery).

4) Pass your created javascript function as an OnSuccess handler to the AjaxOptions when you create your ajax form (Ajax.BeginForm)

Comment: I've put table in partial view, _list.cshtml, and in index view I call 
<div id="timeKeeperList">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_List", Model.TimeKeepers); }
</div>
The tables was updated, but the modal did not closed automatically.